# I want the page to redirect after the user clicks all the links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code I got it from an old post, but it doesn't seem to be working anymore please help. I can't even click on the links anymore, but my main goal is to have the user click on all the links and then have the page redirect to another page on my website.

```js
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var anchors, clicked_count, clicked, i, cur_anchor, my_anchor_id;

    anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    clicked_count = 0;
    clicked = {};

    for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        cur_anchor = anchors[i];
        cur_anchor.setAttribute("link", i);
        cur_anchor.onclick = function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault();

            my_anchor_id = this.getAttribute("link");
            if (!(my_anchor_id in clicked)) {
                clicked[my_anchor_id] = null;
                if (++clicked_count === anchors.length) {
                    console.log("WOULD BE REDIRECTING");
                    //window.location.href = "facebook.com";
                }
            }
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

```html
<a href="#Link1" id="link">Some Text 1</a>
<a href="#Link2" id="link">Some Text 2</a>
<a href="#Link3" id="link">Some Text 3</a>
```

Comment: what exactly issue you are facing?

Comment: I did a test run of your code & that is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Please try it now

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var anchors, clicked_count, clicked, i, cur_anchor, my_anchor_id;

    anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    clicked_count = 0;
    clicked = {};

    for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        cur_anchor = anchors[i];
        cur_anchor.setAttribute("class", i);
        cur_anchor.onclick = function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault();

            my_anchor_id = this.getAttribute("class");
            if (!(my_anchor_id in clicked)) {
                clicked[my_anchor_id] = null;
                if (++clicked_count === anchors.length) {
                    window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
                }
            }
        };
    }
};
```

```html
<a href="#Link1" class="link">Some Text 1</a>
<a href="#Link2" class="link">Some Text 2</a>
<a href="#Link3" class="link">Some Text 3</a>
```

Comment: The redirect works, but I can't click on the links when I add the urls.

Comment: use this for redirect to specific url from the href attribute. window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **fix your HTML** you cannot have multiple the same `id` attributes as you got three times `id="link"`. Please change it to `class="link"` to avoid problems.

Like this:

```
<a href="#Link1" class="link">Some Text 1</a>
<a href="#Link2" class="link">Some Text 2</a>
<a href="#Link3" class="link">Some Text 3</a>
```

If you are using jQuery, you can achieve what you described (that is *redirecting after clicking three different links*) with much simpler code.

Below is a example solution with comments, that will check which links were already clicked and redirect only if user click all three of them, no matter in what order he clicks them:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // Create an array for clicked elements
    var clicked = [];
      
    // Create a click event for every link with class "link"
    $('.link').click(function() {

      // Check if we didn't clicked that link yet
      if (clicked.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) === -1) {

        // If we didn't add it's href attribute to "clicked" array"
        clicked.push($(this).attr('href'));
      }
        
      // If number of clicked links is 3, redirect
      if (clicked.length === 3) {
        console.log('REDIRECT');
        // location.href = 'http://put-your-url-here.com'
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#Link1" class="link">Some Text 1</a>
<a href="#Link2" class="link">Some Text 2</a>
<a href="#Link3" class="link">Some Text 3</a>
```

Comment: Where do I put the link so that it will redirect?

Comment: @Erin in the place of `console.log('REDIRECT');` you just put there `location.href = "http://my-url.com"` (with your URL of course)

Comment: None of it's working for me. I use <script></script> right?

Comment: @Erin `<script>` tag is where you put all of your javascript. That is from `$(document).ready` to the end of scripts. Not just for `location.href` or `window.open` - https://jsfiddle.net/L5faedzv/2/ here you have working fiddle with use of window.open

Comment: @wilq I know that, I just wanted to make sure I didn't need to include `type="text/javascript"` or something, because I put in everything else the redirect still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    window.onload = function () {
        var anchors, clicked_count, clicked, i, cur_anchor, my_anchor_id;

        anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        clicked_count = 0;
        clicked = [];

        for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            cur_anchor = anchors[i];
            cur_anchor.setAttribute("link", i);
            cur_anchor.onclick = function (e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                e.preventDefault();


                window.location.href = "https://facebook.com";
            }
        }

    };
```

Comment: Any explanation ?